# Marklogic how to do a field-range-query with a date using Structured Query

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to do the following the following query using a structured query

```
cts:search(fn:collection(),cts:field-range-query("PublishDateTime",">",xs:dateTime("2016-08-10T00:00:00")))
```

The above returns results on the console but using the structured query below, No records are returned.

```
<ns2:query xmlns:ns2="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" >
    <ns2:range-query>
        <ns2:field name="PublishDateTime"/>
        <ns2:value>2016-08-10T00:00:00</ns2:value>
        <ns2:range-operator>&gt;</ns2:range-operator>
    </ns2:range-query>
</ns2:query>
```

Anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for range query](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_64316) say range-operator accepts the values "One of LT, LE, GT, GE, EQ, NE. Default: EQ."  Try that instead of &gt;